# After onActivityResult the screen rotate to landscape

Tags: android

I'm tring to open camera and take a picture and after that to store the image in a listView with image. the problem is, after i take the picture and return to my activity result the screen returns in landscape and a short while after rotates back to portrait and make me to lost the data. why this is happened? here is my code:

```
  if (requestCode == mActions.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap imageCapturred = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        list.add(new ModelChat(null , false,null ,imageCapturred));
        mChatAdapter = new ChatRowAdapter(this , list);
        mChatList.setAdapter(mChatAdapter);
        System.out.println("Get Image from Camera");
    }
```

but the way..
I dont want using `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`
Any idea how to slove it?

Answer (score 4):

make a intent as class variable and set the value of this intent when  `onActivityResult` called like this.camaraData =data;
and also save this class variable in `onsavedInstanceState()` function
and restore this value in `onRestoreInstanceState()` or in `oncreate()`
eg.

```
            public class yourActivityName extends Activity
            {

            Intent camaraData ;boolean chkCalled;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
                // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
                if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                    // Restore value of members from saved state
              camaraData =savedInstanceState.getParcelable("camaraData");   
             if(!chkCalled){
    onActivityResult(mActions.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE,Activity.Result_OK,camaraData); 
    chkCalled=true;
        }
    }  
            ...... /* your code goes here */  ...
    }


            @Override
            public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // Save the user's current game state
                savedInstanceState..putParcelable("camaraData", camaraData);    
            // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
                super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            }
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data) 
            {
               camaraData=data;
            if (requestCode==mActions.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE&&resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                    Bitmap imageCapturred = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    list.add(new ModelChat(null , false,null ,imageCapturred));
                    mChatAdapter = new ChatRowAdapter(this , list);
                    mChatList.setAdapter(mChatAdapter);
                    System.out.println("Get Image from Camera");
                }
            }

            public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
                super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);       
                // Restore state members from saved instance
                camaraData = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("camaraData");     
        if(!chkCalled){ 
               onActivityResult(mActions.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE,
Activity.Result_OK,camaraData); 
chkCalled=true;
        }
            }

        }
```

call only one way to handle this either in `onCreate()`or by using `onRestoreInstanceState()` function your problem will me solve as per your requirement or you can keep both but call of `onActivityResult(...)` function only from one place by checking whether its called or not by using `boolean` value as given in example

Answer (score 0):

In general, what you need to do if you want your activity to survive screen rotation is save/restore your activites instance state. 
Have a look at [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)